# p5.js not drawing a 3d box

Tags: processing, p5.js

I am creating a simulator using P5.js. Within the simulator, I need a green box, however it does not seem to be appearing. The code is below:

```
var outputs = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400, WEBGL);
  background(200);

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    drop = new Water(width / 2, height / 2, 0, 1);
    outputs[i] = drop;
  }
}

function draw() {
  push();
  translate(200, 150, 0);
  stroke(0, 100, 0);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  box(150, 150, 150);
  pop();

  for (var i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++) {
    outputs[i].update();
  }

  background(200);
}
```

Here is the water class:

```
function Water(x_, y_, z_, yVel_) {

  this.r = random(0.25, 1);

  this.xOff = random(-(this.r / 10), (this.r / 10));
  this.zOff = random(-(this.r / 10), (this.r / 10));

  this.x = x_ + this.xOff;
  this.y = y_;
  this.z = z_ + this.zOff;

  this.yVel = yVel_;

  this.pos = createVector(this.x, this.y, this.z);

  this.show = function() {
    push();
    translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.pos.z);
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    sphere(this.r * 2);
    pop();
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.vel = createVector(random(-(this.r / 10), (this.r / 10)), 
                this.yVel, random(-(this.r / 10),
                (this.r / 10)));
    this.pos.add(this.vel);

    this.show();
  }
}
```

This is a web based simulation, with another module which appears to be working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you leave a link to your `Water` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the parts that require the `Water` class, and moving the `background` function call to the top of `draw`, it seems to work just fine.

So, the problem is

- Either that you forgot to put `background` on top
- Or something's wrong with the `Water` class.

---

Here's your code with the mentioned problems fixed.

```js
var outputs = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  push();
  translate(200, 150, 0);
  stroke(0, 100, 0);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  box(150, 150, 150);
  pop();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not rendering because you're background is over your scene

```
function draw() {
  background(200);
  push();
  translate(200, 150, 0);
  stroke(0, 100, 0);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  box(150, 150, 150);
  pop();

  for (var i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++) {
    outputs[i].update();
  }


}
```

What your doing is drawing the box and the drops and you cover it all up with your background
if you don't have a background you will see how p5.js renders animation
p5.js not moving it, its just looping through draw every frame and the background covers up the previous frame